# Swift iOS scaling down large image to fit in thumbnail collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, image, aspect-ratio

I have a collectionView composed of imageView thumbnails (width: 60, height: 45).

I have large images that I need to resize to fit into these thumbnails. I don't want to simply assign these large images to the small ImageViews as it negatively impacts performance.

When I resize these images, should I set the width to 60 and height 45? Exact 1-to-1 to fit in the thumbnail cell?

Or should I instead try and maintain the aspect ratio of the original image? Set the height 45 and then calculate the width to maintain the aspect ratio? So the width will not be exactly 60.

If the scaled down image is not exactly 45x60, when I assign the image to the 45x60 imageView, the image will have to re-draw it self to fit the imageView? Will this negatively impact performance?

Comment: You could copy the images, save them with jpeg compression, and then read them from the documents directory and display them as your thumbnails. That might be an approach.

Comment: the images are uploaded from my app, so i want to resize the images in Swift. I just want to know if I should hardcode 45x60 size or try and maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: That's really a choice that you are going to have to make depending on the needs of your application.  If you don't maintain the aspect ratio then the thumbnail would be a distorted representation of the image if the original image doesn't have the same aspect ratio.  If you have any control whatsoever on the back end, the even better thing to do would be to have the back end only feed your application the thumbnail-sized images so you're not downloading a large amount of data for the full image when all you want is the thumbnail.

Comment: If I set the thumbnail size to the exact size of the imageView in each cell (45x60), then I'm assuming in my collectionView with 100 thumbnails, that it will load very fast since the image is exact same size of the imageView? If the image is slightly different (maintaining aspect ratio) say 45 x 70, then it will have to be redrawn to fit the imageView size(45x60). Will this be a big performance hit when I load my collectionView?

Comment: @ScottThompson -

Comment: For such a small difference in sizes, I don't think performance will be an issue.  If you're trying to scale down large images then I would think yes... performance will be bad.  As with all things performance, however, your best bet is to try it and see if it's a problem :-(